# Ubuntu cannot see portable hdd with 2 partitions

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, partitioning, external-hard-drive, mount

I don't know why but Ubuntu v9.10 isn't showing up one of it's partitions in my portable HDD.

Only the 2nd partition is shown, and I can't find the 1st one.

What might be a solution to this?

Comment: Run `sudo tail -f /var/log/messages` and see what happens when you plug your hard drive.

Comment: Also the output of `sudo fdisk -l` would help alot.